# we couldn't complete this action. Try a different payment method or contact us. [OR_CCREU_02]

Tags: kotlin, payment-gateway, google-pay

I implement google pay from google pay docs and when i am testing it in test environment i am getting an error

> "we couldn't complete this action. Try a different payment method or
> contact us. [OR_CCREU_02]"

i spend almost 4 days to resolving this error but nothing helps for me.
Anyone have any idea how to resolve this error and test google pay transaction for Test Environment

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxrYr.jpg)
this is my json:

```
{
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "apiVersionMinor": 0,
    "allowedPaymentMethods": [
        {
            "type": "CARD",
            "parameters": {
                "allowedAuthMethods": [
                    "PAN_ONLY",
                    "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"
                ],
                "allowedCardNetworks": [
                    "AMEX",
                    "DISCOVER",
                    "JCB",
                    "MASTERCARD",
                    "VISA"
                ],
                "billingAddressRequired": true,
                "billingAddressParameters": {
                    "format": "FULL"
                }
            },
            "tokenizationSpecification": {
                "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
                "parameters": {
                    "gateway": "example",
                    "gatewayMerchantId": "DCR2DFGGHP7EJS"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "transactionInfo": {
        "totalPrice": "1000",
        "totalPriceStatus": "FINAL",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "currencyCode": "USD"
    },
    "merchantInfo": {
        "merchantName": "example"
    },
    "shippingAddressParameters": {
        "phoneNumberRequired": false,
        "allowedCountryCodes": [
            "US",
            "GB"
        ]
    },
    "shippingAddressRequired": true
}
```

i followed the google docs but nothing help for me

> **Edited**

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfUlG.png)

[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usmdJ.png)

[image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88I8B.png)

Comment: Your screenshot shows the "add card screen". This won't work. If you need test cards please see here: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite - You can join https://groups.google.com/g/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data in order to see test cards in the payment sheet

Comment: i already joind the Group. please see the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfUlG.png

Comment: ok cool. but why does your first screenshot show the "add card" screen? if you are part of the group and you are using the test environment the payment sheet will display the test cards.

Comment: @domi could you please explain where i can get test cards in payment sheet

Comment: You need to join the above mentioned group and then trigger a payment in test env with the same Google account you used to join the group. If this does not work, please try it with the quick-start app: https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart - clone the repo and open the kotlin (or java) folder with Android Studio to run the app.

Comment: @domi Thank for your help it worked, i get all test card after using same email : https://i.stack.imgur.com/usmdJ.png , but when i hit to continue button its giving an error [OR_BIBED_01], see the image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/88I8B.png

Comment: I copied your payload and created this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-pay-react-9jjsuz?file=src%2FApp.js It works for me. I do receive a token.

Comment: hey @domi i am implemening native google pay. from using this documentation: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial i am confused what i need to add gateway type in gateway(in place of braintree). please see this image : https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial

Comment: I posted an answer and added a configuration for braintree

Comment: i am not using braintree gateway, i just want to know what is the gateway type i need to mention there for google pay native?

Comment: You have to work together with a gateway. Google Pay does support a lot of them: https://developers.google.com/pay/api#participating-processors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first image shows the "add card" screen. You are trying to add a new test card. This won't work and results in `OR_CCREU_02`. In order for the Google Pay sheet to show test cards when using the test environment you have to join this Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data

After joining the group, trigger a payment in test env with the same Google account you used to join the group. Now the Google Pay sheet should show all the test cards the PSP supports:

[image: Google Pay payment sheet]

**Update:**

For Braintree use a gateway configration similar to:

```java
new JSONObject() {{
  put("type", "PAYMENT_GATEWAY");
  put("parameters", new JSONObject() {{
    put("gateway", "braintree");
    put("braintree:apiVersion", "v1");
    put("braintree:sdkVersion", "braintree.client.3.40.0");
    put("braintree:merchantId", "your_merchant_id");
    put("braintree:clientKey", "your_client_key");
  }});
}};
```